# I have several lists approx 50 i want the lists to get printed using for loop. how can i dynamically write name under print statement?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```py
list1=['a','a']

list2=['b','bc']

list3=['c','cd']

for i in range(0,3):
    print("list"+str(i))
```

I tried this part but this was not working as expected.

Comment: In what data structure do these list lie, have you just declared 50 individual lists seperatly?

Comment: You should not have 50 individual lists to begin with. This problem has its solution further up the code.

Comment: I have declared 14 lists according to the filter that needs to be applied under isin part of pandas filtering . so i need list to be under isin part using for loop